# Controller method is not detecting any parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'am trying to send an id in my url but my controller doesn't get that value

```
$("#ChangeSlideForm").on("submit", function(){

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url + "Visualiser/ChangeSlide/21",
            success: function (response) {
              alert(response);
                // $("#deleteConfirm").modal('hide');
                // jQuery(function RefreshPageAdd($){
                //     $('#deleteConfirm').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                //       location.reload();
                //     });
                // });

            }
          });
        });
```

My View

```
<div id="bodyChange" class="modal-body">
  <form id = "ChangeSlideForm" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>Visualiser/ChangeSlide" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <label class="btnSlide btn btn-outline-success">
    Zip <input class="file" name="file[]" type="file" hidden>
  </label>
  <label class="btnSlide btn btn-outline-success">
    Csv <input class="file" name ="file[]" type="file" hidden>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-6">Ajouter</button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

My controller header :

```
    public function ChangeSlide($id){
     print_r($id);
    }
```

When I a put the id in the url directly then the parameter is accessible otherwise when I pass with ajax, It doesn't detect the parameter.

Comment: You're using a POST request, but there's no `data` in your `$.ajax` call's options. You need to add something like `data: "id=21",` In the developer tools of the browser (press F12) you can double-check each request in the console, including all headers and parameters.

Comment: What you are intended to do?? Make an ajax call or form post?? I can see both form action as well as the ajax operation. Depending on your requirements, I can suggest to you the answer.

Comment: where is the variable `base_url`defined? do you get any browser console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

**The HTML**

```
<form id="ChangeSlideForm" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>Visualiser/ChangeSlide/21" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div id="bodyChange" class="modal-body">
    <label class="btnSlide btn btn-outline-success"> Zip
      <input class="file" name="file[]" type="file" hidden>
    </label>
    <label class="btnSlide btn btn-outline-success"> Csv
      <input class="file" name="file[]" type="file" hidden>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-6">Ajouter</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**The Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#ChangeSlideForm").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            data    : $(this).serializeArray(), 
            success : function(data)
            {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (xhr)
            {
                console.log(xhr)
            }
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
 public function ChangeSlide(){
 print_r($this->uri->segment(3));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing parameter `data` in `$.ajax()`. So your ajax didn't send any data to your controller

Answer (score 0):

When you pass value with ajax then controller method get that value as $this->input->post('id'); not as parameter.

So you have to add following to method

public function ChangeSlide($id = "")
{

}